# Sticky corners in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse

I couldn't google anything about it. Afaik, Windows 8+ has a sticky corners feature where, while using multiple monitors, if the user moves the mouse from one monitor to another at the top or bottom of the screen the mouse sticks in a corner and doesn't leave the monitor. Which, of course, is useful for aiming at "X" buttons, Start menu and so on...

There's a workaround where I just offset the monitors vertically so they're not at the same level and I get **some** "sticky corners" that way but I not all.

I'd like the same functionality in Windows 7. System-only solution desired, third-party app solution acceptable.

Comment: I used to use Dexpot on Windows 7 until Windows 10 shipped with virtual desktops. I seem to remember Dexpot including an option for sticky edges, take a look.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am looking for the same thing.

Comment: @Codeformer Sadly, no. I don't remember if I tried the Dexpot but I preferred not to have a 3rd-party app anyway. So I've stuck with my workaround.